# InvalidAccessKeyId when attempting to upload file to AWS S3 from Javascript using PHP pre-signed URL

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm getting the following error when attempting to use a pre-signed URL to upload a file to a private S3 bucket.

```
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code>
    <Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message>
    <AWSAccessKeyId></AWSAccessKeyId>
    <RequestId></RequestId>
    <HostId></HostId>
</Error>
```

I have a EC2 webserver that has assumed an IAM role with the following permissions.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*",
                "kms:*",
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And with the following trust relationship.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

When a user wants to upload, my Javascript will first call my server to get the pre-signed URL from my PHP script.

```
$s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version'     => '2006-03-01',
    'region'      => $region
]);

$formInputs = ['acl' => 'private'];

$options = [
    ['acl' => 'private'],
    ['bucket' => $_ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET']],
    ['starts-with', '$key', $pth],
];

$expires = '+1 hours';

$postObject = new \Aws\S3\PostObjectV4(
    $s3Client,
    $_ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET'],
    $formInputs,
    $options,
    $expires
);

$fattr = $postObject->getFormAttributes();
$finput = $postObject->getFormInputs();
```

Once that is returned, I then make an Ajax call to S3 to post the file.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("acl", fp["acl"]);
fd.append("key", fp['Path']);
fd.append("X-Amz-Credential", fp["X-Amz-Credential"]);
fd.append("X-Amz-Algorithm", fp["X-Amz-Algorithm"]);
fd.append("X-Amz-Date", fp["X-Amz-Date"]);
fd.append("Policy", fp["Policy"]);
fd.append("X-Amz-Signature", fp["X-Amz-Signature"]);
fd.append('file', file);

$.ajax({
    url: fp['action'],
    type: 'post',
    data: fd,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
})...
```

This is where the error then occurs. This all previously worked when I used hard coded credentials but when I switched to an assigned IAM role for the EC2 it no longer works.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Try adding `'profile' => 'default'` when initiating S3Client.

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions here that will get you better idea:

1. Remove ~/.aws/credentials along with ~/.aws/config
2. Check your $region is same as aws resource(s) region
3. Use aws cli to test the aws resource

i.e.

```
aws sts get-caller-identity --debug

aws s3 ls
```